# Asynchronous method in node js is not working

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

This is the most simple async code you can ever imagine but I don't know why I can't figure out why it is not working.
This is my code:

```
const fs = require('fs');
fs.readdirSync('./', function (err, files) {
if (err)
  console.log('Error!!', err);
else
  console.log("Result!!",files);
});
```

This is my terminal:

% node main.js

%

[image: Terminal image]

Literally nothing happens...

Comment: Change `readdirSync` to `readdir`.

Answer (score 0):

"readdirSync" is a synchronized function and you are using it as async style, use "readdir" instead or just get result from function return https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/node-js-fs-readdirsync-method/

Answer (score 0):

Use `fs.readdir()` or `fs.readdirSync()` to read the contents of a directory.

This piece of code reads the content of a folder, both files and subfolders, and returns their relative path:

```js
const fs = require('fs')

const folderPath = '/Users/joe'

fs.readdirSync(folderPath)
```